# Removing roles from a user then adding them back in Discord.py (Using Repl.it)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I’m currently trying to make 2 commands, a mute and unmute command for my discord bot in python. The command is supposed to remove all the roles off a user, then add the “Muted” role. After this, when we unmute the user using the unmute command, the “Muted” role gets removed and the user’s previous roles are assigned back. I’m coding the bot in Repl.it, so if a database is needed for this, would there be anyway to do this using repl.it’s build in database? Thank you so much to anyone who answers this, I’ve been struggling for hours. Here's what I have so far:

````
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
  if member is None:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Please provide a user tag.", \
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0))
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    return

  everyone = ctx.guild.get_role(795989660920053770)
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
  roles = member.roles
  roles.remove(everyone)

  if "userRoles" not in db.keys():
    db["userRoles"] = roles
  else:
    userRoles = db["userRoles"]
    userRoles.append(roles)
    db["userRoles"] = userRoles

  await member.remove_roles(*roles)
  await member.add_roles(role)

  if reason is None:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"***Muted {member}***", \
            colour = discord.Colour.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"***Muted {member}***", \
            description = f"Reason: {reason}", \
            colour = discord.Colour.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
  return

@mute.error
async def mute_error(self, ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "***You don't have the right permissions for that.***", \
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0))
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    return

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def unmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
  if member is None:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Please provide a user tag.", \
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0))
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    return

  userRoles = f"{member.id}_roles"
  
  await member.remove_roles("Muted")
  await member.add_roles(db[userRoles])

  if reason is None:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"***Unmuted {member}***", \
            colour = discord.Colour.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"***Unmuted {member}***", \
            description = f"Reason: {reason}", \
            colour = discord.Colour.green())
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
  return

@unmute.error
async def unmute_error(self, ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "***You don't have the right permissions for that.***", \
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0))
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)```
````

Comment: So if you've been fighting for hours, show us your best attempt. We won't write all the code for you.

Comment: I've edited my question with the code for muting and unmuting that I have so far. Sorry for not including it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re just looking to make some member role updates, you shouldn’t need to use a database and using repl.it should be fine. For your commands, you could just use the member object’s [add role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Member.add_roles) and [remove role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Member.remove_roles) functions. You did mention that you were only doing this for commands, however if you do need to wait x amount of time to unmute the member, I would highly recommend using the asyncio module’s [sleep function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=sleep#asyncio.sleep).

I know that you’re new to StackOverflow, so just note for next time to maybe include a bit more detail in regard to what you’ve tried so far as it really helps to giving a better idea of what it is that you’re trying to do.

Comment: Okay basically. What I'm going for is a mute function that removes all of a user's roles, and saves them somewhere so when the user is unmuted, they will be assigned all of their previous roles back. I thought I would need to use a database to store the user's roles but if there's no need for one then that works too.

Comment: One thing I did forget to mention is the main reason I am having an issue is because there could be multiple people muted, so I'd probably need a different variable storing each of their individual roles, so when they get unmuted they could get their proper roles reassigned back. I'm fairly new to databases so that's why I resorted to asking for help, I just couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to do, but I would highly recommend that you do this a different way. Discord works in that if you have ANY role that is denied the Send Message Permission, you are not able to send messages. The ideal way to do this would just be to have a role for muted people that denies access to sending messages.

Comment: StarbuckBarista this was the original method I wanted to use but the issue is that some people have roles that overwrite the Muted role. For example some custom roles allow access to chats that for some reason overwrite the muted role which has no talking permissions. So I figured the best way to solve this would be to remove all other roles and assign the muted role.

Comment: Then the issue that you are dealing with is Channel Permissions. These permissions only apply to specific channels and will override any pre-set permissions. All you need to do is go into these channels and set the muted role's permission to send messages to X.

Comment: StarbucksBarista. You’re right, this did work as well. Although when I use this method I cannot mute any admins. Of course I’d trust admins enough to not need the functionality of muting them, but you never know, you know? But if there isn’t a method of saving a user’s roles then this is the method I’ll stick with.